# Android Service Unable to start intent & NullPointerException

Tags: android, service

I'm creating a background service (in its own process) and am having a lot of trouble getting it to work.  I'm trying to launch it when the application starts, and I'm getting the unable to start service with intent error in the log.  I've been going through forums, examples, (and google) and couldn't find what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the error I'm getting:
E/AndroidRuntime(1398): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.test.alarms.AlarmService@41550cb0 with Intent { cmp=xxxx }: java.lang.NullPointerException

In the activity I have:

```
startService(new Intent(AlarmService.class.getName()));
```

The service class is:

```
package com.test.alarms;


public class AlarmService extends Service{

Context context; 

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
//code to execute when the service is first created
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
//code to execute when the service is shutting down
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
//code to execute when the service is starting up
    Intent i = new Intent(context, StartActivity.class);
    PendingIntent detailsIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);

    NotificationManager notificationSingleLine = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notificationDropText = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Alarm for...", System.currentTimeMillis());

    CharSequence from = "Time for...";
    CharSequence message = "Alarm Text";        
    notificationDropText.setLatestEventInfo(this, from, message, detailsIntent);

    notificationDropText.vibrate = new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 500};        
    notificationSingleLine.notify(0, notificationDropText);
}
```

}

The manifest file has:

```
<service
        android:name=".AlarmService"
        android:process=":remote">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.test.alarms.AlarmService"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the problem is you have overridden OnCreate and OnDestroy  but you are not calling the super.Oncreate() and super.onDestroy().

If this does not work try

```
startService(new Intent(context , AlarmService.class));
```

Edit:
Also use this in onStart

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, StartActivity.class);
```

instead of

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, StartActivity.class);
```

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(1398): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.test.alarms.AlarmService@41550cb0 with Intent { cmp=xxxx }: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Your question title is misleading, you should have said you are getting null pointer exception. Did you try using **this** instead of context as suggested in the edit

Comment: you should posts the whole call stack and post on what line you are getting Nullpointer exception. Edit your question

Comment: Thanks for your help, after digging, I found that I needed to add the vibrate permission

Answer (score 5):

Acording to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), you need to check whether passing intent is null (for restarting after process killed) or not (normal operation) inside you onStartCommand(Intent intent,int,int);

Better design,

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if(intent != null){
        handleCommand(intent);
    }
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) more